# How to recreate compareTo method in java?

Tags: java, compareto

How does the `compareTo()` method for Dates work here in java? I know that when you compare two dates the result will always be `0` if equal, `1` if the date being 
compared inside the `compareTo()` parameter is older, and `-1` if the date inside the parameter is more recent.

```
//Just an example

String[] da = {"01/14/1975", "08/20/1975", "08/20/1975"};
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date d1 = new Date();
Date d2 = new Date();


//this outputs 1 because d2 is older than d1
d1 = f.parse(da[1]);            
d2 = f.parse(da[0]);     
System.out.println(d1.compareTo(d2));

//this outputs 0 because dates are the same
d1 = f.parse(da[1]);            
d2 = f.parse(da[2]);     
System.out.println(d1.compareTo(d2));

//this outputs -1 because d2 is more recent than d1
d1 = f.parse(da[0]);            
d2 = f.parse(da[1]);     
System.out.println(d1.compareTo(d2));
```

Now I want to compare dates without using `compareTo()` method or any built-in method in java. As much as possible I want to use just the basic operators in java.

What is the computation or the algorithm of the `compareTo()` method in comparing dates that enable it to return `-1`, `0`, and `1`?

**Edit:**
In the case at the sample problem at my book, using java.util.Date is forbidden, what is supposed to be done is to create your own date object like this:

```
public class DatesObj
{
    protected int day, month, year;

    public DatesObj (int mm, int dd, int yyyy) {
        month = mm;
        day = dd;        
        year = yyyy;
    }

    public int getMonth() { return month; }

    public int getDay() { return day; }

    public int getYear() { return year; }
```

}

Now how do I compare this as if like they're `int` and determine which is old and which is newer??

Comment: Just compare `Date.getTime()`.

Comment: Not really to you question, but you should be using `LocalDate`; the old date api is terribly inconsistent.

Comment: java.util.Date does `return (thisTime<anotherTime ? -1 : (thisTime==anotherTime ? 0 : 1));` There is no magic in there.

Comment: A Date is, at its core, just a number - so it's a numeric comparison: is one number bigger than the other number?

Comment: I do second @ElliottFrisch in that you should be using `LocalDate`, especially if you are not interested in timezones, time-of-day, accidental millisecond differences etc.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes I'm aware of that, but I am just trying to solve a sample exercise from my book at school. By the way, this is not a homework, I'm just doing a little practice

Comment: Did you want to know about comparing `Date` objects specifically, or just "dates" in general?

Comment: @JessieBrianRevil If you're going to do that, I would prefer `Long.compare(d1.getTime(), d2.getTime())`

Comment: @KevinAnderson I want to know about Date objects on how to compare them as if like they're normal int numbers, if that is possible and without using any built in methods like getTime, etc....

Comment: @KevinAnderson edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to compare two dates just as if they were just plain-old integers, you must first turn each date into a plain-old integer.  The easiest way to turn a year/month/day representation of a date into a plain-old integer, that can be effectively compared with plain-old integers from other dates, is to line the pieces up in exactly that order: year first, month next, day last:

```
//  in DateObj class....
public int getDateInt() {
    return (yyyy * 10000) + (mm * 100) + dd;
}
```

So for March 19, 2019, you get 20190319, and for December 7, 1941 you get 19411207; by comparing the "integerized" versions of the dates you can see that:

- 19411207 < 20190319, just as December 7, 1941 is earlier than March 19, 2019;
- 20190319 > 19411207, just as March 19, 2019 is later than December 7, 1941;
- 19411207 != 20190319, just as December 7, 1941 and March 19, 2019 are different dates

You're limited to dates within the Common Era and no more than about 200,000 years into the future with this particular implementation.  But with a little tweaking, you could easily easily handle dates outside these ranges, an exercise that I will, as the textbooks so often say, leave as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Now this is what I'm looking for. It's much simpler

Answer (score 2):

Implement Comparable and override compareTo().

```
class DatesObj implements Comparable<DatesObj>{
    protected int day, month, year;

    public DatesObj(int mm, int dd, int yyyy) {
        month = mm;
        day = dd;
        year = yyyy;
    }

    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public int getYear() { return year; }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(DatesObj o) {

        int diff = this.year - o.year;

        if(diff != 0) {
            return diff;
        }

        diff = this.month - o.month;

        if(diff != 0) {
            return diff;
        }

        return this.day - o.day;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Compare the years. If the years of both the dates are same, compare the months.
If the months are same, compare the dates.

```
public int compareDate(DatesObj d) { 
    if (this.year != d.year) { 
        if (this.year > d.year)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }
    if (this.month != d.month) {
        if (this.month > d.month)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }
    if (this.day != d.day) {
        if (this.day > d.day)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ref : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Ref : https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar

create own class with  [**`Interface Comparable`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

```
class DateCompare implements Comparable<Date>
{
    protected int day, month, year;

    public DateCompare(int mm, int dd, int yyyy) {
        month = mm;
        day = dd;
        year = yyyy;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Date o) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(o);
        int diff = this.year - cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        if(diff != 0) {
            return diff;
        }

        diff = this.month - cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);

        if(diff != 0) {
            return diff;
        }

        return this.day - cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    }
    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public int getYear() { return year; }
}
```

And Other More Helpful
https://gist.github.com/Ashusolanki/fed3b6a680092985ac0ab93ed70fcd7c

```
private String postTime(Date date) 
{
    long postTime = date.getTime();
    long atTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    long diff = atTime - postTime;
    long sec = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    if (sec >= 60) {
        long minit = TimeUnit.MINUTES.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        if (minit >= 60) {
            long hours = TimeUnit.HOURS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

            if (hours >= 24) {
                long days = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                return days + " Days Ago";
            } else {
                return hours + " Hours Ago";
            }
        } else {
            return minit + " Minutes Ago";
        }
    } else {
        return sec + " Secounds Ago";
    }
}
```